# Forbidden error while calling multipart/form-data in rest call

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy, multipartform-data

I am struck with a scenario, I am writing a rest call for which content type is multipart/form-data,i am using jboss 7 server .its working fine in http but its not working in https .

URL i am using : https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/api/space/nsas/cpp/service-management/scripts/add-script

```
Content-type:multipart/form-data;boundary=---------------------------200860455821258037241807020589
```

Payload:

```
---------------------------200860455821258037241807020589
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scriptDesc";
Content-Type: text/plain;charset="us-ascii"
```

This is sample.

ERROR LOG:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
10.216.114.18
Mon Oct 20 17:43:15 2014
```

The same rest call in http is working fine .

Answer (score 0):

If you connect through a apache as reverse proxy, you must configure the same settings you have to port 80 (ProxyPass, etc) to port 443. Maybe in the virtual host `<VirtualHost *.443>`